# Material-UI: Cannot Trigger the onChangeCommitted Event During Testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am having problems testing the `onChangeCommitted` event using the [slider](https://material-ui.com/api/slider/) from `Mui`. In a code sandbox I've recreated a simple implementation of the use of a slider.

Here's the code [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-goldstine-gpjbj?file=/src/App.js:743-758).

The problem I'm having is that while I figured out how to change the `aria-valuenow` property on the slider element itself (span with role="slider") the test does not seem to trigger the `onChangeCommitted` event. This is pretty annoying as i have side effects in the `onChangeCommitted` event that need to be tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSdom actually renders these tests without physical width so a method needed to be mocked with jest.

The actual solution to this problem was to mock `screen.getByRole('slider').getBoundingClientRect` using jest like so:

```
    screen.getByRole('slider').getBoundingClientRect = jest.fn(() => ({
      width: 100,
      height: 10,
      bottom: 10,
      left: 0,
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      right: 0,
      top: 0,
      toJSON: jest.fn(),
    }));
```

Then mouse up and mouse down could be used like so:

```
fireEvent.mouseDown(screen.getByRole('slider'), { buttons: 1, clientX: 30 });
fireEvent.mouseUp(screen.getByRole('slider'), { buttons: 1, clientX: 30 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should trigger a `mouseUp` event in your tests. Referring to the mui docs

```
onChangeCommitted
Callback function that is fired when the mouseup is triggered.

Signature:
function(event: object, value: number | number[]) => void
event: The event source of the callback.
value: The new value.
```

So

```
fireEvent.mouseUp(...
```

instead of `mouseDown`

Comment: I should trigger this on a specific mark right? Because no event works when targeting the marks themself.